# Várias "Divs" dentro de um foreach

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

Quero por um sistema de ranking com estrelas tipo "imdb", mas o elemento só aparece uma vez dentro do ciclo.

Script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {
            $("#rateYo").rateYo({

                onChange: function (rating, rateYoInstance) {

                    $(this).next().text(rating);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Html:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.catequizandoSessao)
{
    <tr>
        <td>                          
            <div id="rateYo"></div>
            <div class="counter"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {
            $(".rak").rateYo({

                onChange: function (rating, rateYoInstance) {

                    $(this).next().text(rating);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

@foreach (var item in ViewBag.catequizandoSessao)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="rateYo" class="rak" ></div>
            <div class="counter"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```